# How correctly store elements in char array in C?

Tags: c, arrays, char

I am sure it's pretty obvious, but I haven't been able to figure this out for a couple hours. I need to take input (words, strings) from the user and store it in the array, and then I need to access these elements by their index or something similar.
I've tried both frets and scanf but couldn't make it work.
Here's what I have so far:

```
typedef struct 
{
   char components[MAX_STRING];
   int numComp;
   char weightingSheme[MAX_STRING][50];
   int numOfSchemes;
}  CourseComponents; 

char input [MAX_STRING]
CourseComponents newCourses;
int *Comp = &newCourses.numComp;
*Comp = 0;
int *numOfSchemes = &newCourses.numOfSchemes;
*numOfSchemes = 0;
for (i=0;i<newCourses.numComp;i++) 
{
    printf("Enter next component name: ");
    scanf("%s", input);
    strcpy(&newCourses.components[i], input);  
}
```

Comment: What is 'newCourses'?

Comment: What is the type of `newCourses.components[i]`, is it an array char or an array of pointers?

Comment: it's structure. i'll edit post

Comment: `char components[MAX_STRING][50];` will not solve your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char components[MAX_STRING];
```

This only holds a "single" string.  You probably want to declare it like this;

```
char components[MAX_ELEMS][MAX_STRING];
```

That's an array of strings, more precisely an array of array of chars (each string a fixed 
length which can be wasteful).
This will get you up and running but it's not what I would call "production quality"
You likely don't want hardcoded lengths like this.

Comment: yea, i don't really understand callock by now :) just go with it

Comment: how i then copy elements to 2-dimensional array?